# How to test for and count dynamically numbered classnames with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, classname

I have my object like so:

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('decode-text')[0];
```

It is a list of html elements that look like:

```
<div class="decode-text">
    <div class="cycleText">
        <div class="cycle-0"> 
            <div class="text-animation">hey</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cycle-1"> 
            <div class="text-animation">you</div>
        </div>      
        <div class="cycle-2"> 
            <div class="text-animation">guys</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will just use `indexof` but want to understand why `.contains` returns false?

```
text.classList.contains('cycleText'); = false // why
```

Also any recommendations on getting the number of `'cycle-*'` class names in this node list?

Comment: What is `nodeList`?

Comment: What does it contain?

Comment: Oops! sorry. corrected

Comment: The reason why it's false is because `decode-text` div doesn't have the class `cycleText`

Comment: Also, your title and question don't really match...

Comment: You also do understand that `document.getElementsByClassName` itself returns a nodeList, but you only access the first one

Comment: Ah, I see. How can I test all nested nodes for the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using css attribute selectors. The `^` means "starts with":

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="cycle-"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

`classList` is a list of classes assigned to the current DOM element, and does not include the classes of its children.

The only entry of the list is `decode-text`.